# Bash Script reading Variables from Source file showing No such File or Directory Error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've got a really simple bash script resetting my IpTables Rules. It reads the configuration parameters from another "Config-File" containing bash variables. Therefore I use the keyword "source".

I am running a debian Server with Stable Packages.
Bash is running in Version

> GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

When I execute the script on my debian-Server the output prints the following text:

```
: No such file or directoryptables
: No such file or directoryptables
: No such file or directoryptables
: No such file or directoryptables
: No such file or directoryptables
: No such file or directoryptables
: No such file or directoryp6tables
: No such file or directoryp6tables
: No such file or directoryp6tables
: No such file or directoryp6tables
: No such file or directoryp6tables
: No such file or directoryp6tables
```

Here the content of the Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG=../config/easywall.cfg

if [ -f $CONFIG ];
then
source $CONFIG
fi

eval $IPTABLES -F
eval $IPTABLES -X
eval $IPTABLES -t nat -F
eval $IPTABLES -t nat -X
eval $IPTABLES -t mangle -F
eval $IPTABLES -t mangle -X
eval $IP6TABLES -F
eval $IP6TABLES -X
eval $IP6TABLES -t nat -F
eval $IP6TABLES -t nat -X
eval $IP6TABLES -t mangle -F
eval $IP6TABLES -t mangle -X

exit 0
```

And the content of the Config-File:

```
!/bin/bash
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
IP6TABLES=/sbin/ip6tables
```

Has anybody an Idea why I get this error?

Comment: Could be carriage return characters in any of the files. Run `od -c filename` and look for `\r` characters. Also, the `eval`s are useless, the semicolon is useless, and there's a `#` missing in `!/bin/bash`. If you find carriage return characters, convert file to Unix line endings with `dos2unix filename`.

Comment: Try to add an `else echo "No config file!"; exit 1` to the `if` statement, to see wheter the file was found. I suspect that the config isn't read and the script continues with empty variables. You can also add an `echo "$IPTABLES"` and `echo "$IP6TABLES"` to check whether the `source` worked out as expected.

Comment: Hi Jens! Thanks a lot for your super fast answer. The problem have been some `\r\n` characters in the config-File. Converting the file with dos2unix worked for me.

Comment: @J.Pylypiw: Also remember `!/bin/bash` is not a proper she-bang, add the `#` before it

Answer (score 0):

The Comment from Jens worked for me.

First I used

```
od -c filename
```

to show the content of the bash script and the config file. The content of the bash script was fine, but the content of the config file showed a lot of

```
\r\n
```

in it.
I converted the file with

```
dos2unix filename
```

and the error disappeared.